# ResourceBundleMessageSource: can a value refer to another key in the bundle?

Tags: spring, internationalization, resourcebundle

Given the following properties:

```
app.name=Foo
app.provider=Monkeys LTD
ui.footer.text={0}, brought to you by {1}
```

the text "Foo, brought to you by Monkeys LTD" can be fashioned by putting the above in a resource bundle (`messages_en.properties`), a `MessageSource` bean and calling:

```
messageSource.getMessage("ui.footer.text",args,locale)
```

(where `args` is instantiated with `app.name` and `app.provider`)

Is there a way to shortcut the code, and embed `app.name`/`app.provider` through the property file? E.G. something like:

```
app.name=Foo
app.provider=Monkeys LTD
# reference another value
ui.footer.text="${app.name} brought to you by ${app.provider}"
```

Thanks!